# Integer expected error in script

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to write a simple script to monitor disk usage. I keep getting `integer expression expected errors at line 5`. (`THRESHOLD` value is intentionally set low for testing.)

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df -hP | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=10

if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
    mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' john.kenny@ngc.com << EOF
Your root partition remaining free space is critically low. Used: $CURRENT%
EOF
fi
```

My screen output looks like this

```
./monitor_disk_space.sh: line 5: [: 7
0
22
1
1
1
1
1
1: integer expression expected
```

I'm new to `bash` scripts and especially `awk`. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is because by adding `"` around your logic (` "$CURRENT"` and `"$THRESHOLD"`) you are making them strings. Then you're using an operator that only take an integer (`-gt`) to compare them. You can either remove the `"` or replace `-gt` with `==`.

Comment: @PraveenP No, it's entirely appropriate to quote those variable expansions. If in doubt, _always_ double quote variable expansions in shell scripts! See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you're getting a string of newline-separated values from your pipeline.  This string is not in itself an integer, so it can't be compared to `$THRESHOLD`.

Assuming you'd like to send the message if *any* filesystem is above `$THRESHOLD` percent full, you may use

```
df -hP |  awk '/\// { sub("%", "", $5); print $5 }' |
while read number; do
    if [ "$number" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ]; then
        mail ...
        break
    fi
done
```

This would pass the values, one by one, into a loop that would compare them against `$THRESHOLD`.  If any value is larger, the mail is sent and the loop exits (via the `break`).

I also took the liberty of shortening your pipeline to just `df`+`awk`, as `awk` is more than capable of doing the work of both `grep` and `sed`.

If you only want to check the root partition, then use `df -hP /` in the pipeline above.

Answer (score 0):

```
CURRENT=$(df -hP | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
```

`df -hp` shows a summary of disk usage.

`grep /` filters out the header line.

`awk '{print $5}'` prints the 5th column, which is the percentage usage for each file system.

`sed 's/%//g'` deletes the `%` character. (There's only one, so the `g` is unnecessary. I might have used `tr -d %`, but it doesn't really matter.)

`$(...)` captures the output of the above -- which is going to be multiple lines of output, each of which should contain an integer.

The `-gt` operator requires a *single* integer for each of its arguments.

I think the problem is the `grep /`, which prints every line containing a `/` character (that's probably going to be everything except the header line). Your message indicates that you're interested in the root filesystem.

Changing `grep /` to `grep /$` is one simple solution.

But passing `/` as an argument to the `df` command, so it displays usage *only* for the root file system, is even simpler.

Here's how I might do it:

```
CURRENT=$(df / | awk 'NR == 2 { print $5 }' | tr -d %)
```

You could incorporate the deletion of the `%` character into the `awk` command, but that would be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

why not do it all in `awk`?

```
$ df -hP | 
  awk -v th=10 '/\// {if($5+0>th) 
       system("echo Your ... " $5 " | mail -s \"Disk Space Alert\" xxx@example.com")}'
```